# Better to pick first or last?

Tags: probability, percentage, odds

If 8 balls placed in a bowl and 1 had a prize and 8 ppl are choosing in order each ball. Is it better to go first or last without putting balls back in once each person takes one out?

Comment: If each person taking the ball sees which ball is with the prize, then it's much better to be first :-) . Otherwise, it makes no difference.

Comment: You can easily answer this question with 2 or 3 balls by writing down all the different sequences in which the balls might be withdrawn (there are only 2 and 6 of them, respectively).  What answer do you get?  Generalize.

Comment: Pretty sure this has (in various guises) been asked several times before. ... edit ... indeed, this search turns up what look to be a couple: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=better+to+draw+first

Answer (score 2):

This can be rephrased without changing the math. Imagine eight balls are distributed randomly to eight people standing in a line. One of the balls has a prize. Is it better to be on the far left or on the far right?

Hopefully that change in scenario triggers your intuition that it doesn't matter where you stand (or in what order you select balls from the bowl).